# Passing an array to Javascript in COMET

Tags: php, javascript, comet

I got a basic gist of what COMET does (the constant looping on server side, and printing out `<script>` tags way), so I am just fiddling with it.

I can pass a simple string from PHP to Javascript that way, but what about PHP arrays? Is there anyway to pass a PHP array to Javascript (casting it to a JS array??) using this method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a data format that is a subset of JavaScript, that includes arrays as a data type.

See the [specification](http://json.org) and the [PHP function for creating it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

You can convert your array to JSON and then pass it to JS in your script data.